# How can I overwrite a function in addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, delegates, addeventlistener

In my application, there are several buttons which trigger my function *loadObj(a)*. This function mainly loads the corresponding 3D object using the Three.js library.

When I choose a object and click the corresponding button, a set of three extra buttons appear which allow me to load three variations of the selected object. The code below already works for this scenario using *addEventListener*.

My problem arises when I select a different object, which triggers the code below again. Then, if I click one of the extra buttons for the newly selected object, it loads the correct object, but it also loads the previous one. If I choose a third object, if I click one of the extra buttons, it will not load just the corresponding object, but the previous two as well.

I have read that *addEventListener* works in a cumulative manner, where the functions just keep being added up. So, everytime it runs the loop below, it adds a new *loadObj* with the path of the new model to any other previous *loadObj*.

Is there any way to overwrite a function inside *addEventListener*? I need the previous *loadObj* to be removed from *addEventListener* before adding the new one.

```
    //Solve the scope/closure problem to able to call loadDress inside the "for" loop below
    function delegate(a) {
       return function(){
          loadObj(a)
       }
    }

    for(var item in paths){
       document.getElementById("size" + item).style.display = "inline-block";
       document.getElementById("size" + item).addEventListener("click", delegate(paths[item]), false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run that loop every time you click the button, it's adding an event listener on every run. That's why you keep getting more and more items each time--you keep adding more functions.

Instead of trying to dynamically add new event listeners on dynamically added buttons, you can delegate your event listening to a parent element that is a direct ancestor of all of the buttons. Then you have a single event listener that works for all of your buttons without any extra effort. You just check to make sure a click is from the right type of element and then you can get any relevant information directly from that element (via data- or other attributes on the event object target).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.