# How to Overwrite an addEventListener function?

Tags: javascript

i wanna overwrite addEventListener function from window.
Ive tried the following code:

```
window.__proto__.addEventListener_ = window.__proto__.addEventListener;
window.__proto__.addEventListener = function(...a){
    console.log(...a);
    this.addEventListener_(...a);
}
```

But, when i add a new listener, it starts spamming the event type in console. How can i trigger it only once?

Comment: please check this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994594/how-can-i-overwrite-a-function-in-addeventlistener) may be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `Window.prototype` instead of `window.__proto__`.

```js
Window.prototype.addEventListener_ = Window.prototype.addEventListener;
Window.prototype.addEventListener = function(...a){
    console.log(...a);
    this.addEventListener_(...a);
}
```

And, even better, instead of adding properties to `Window` and polluting the global scope, you could use a block-scoped variable to store the original `addEventListener`, like this :

```js
{
    let addEventListener_ = Window.prototype.addEventListener;
    Window.prototype.addEventListener = function(...a){
        console.log(...a);
        addEventListener_.call(this, ...a);
    }
}
```